# jQuery specific on events for two DOM elements in a single line

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute the same function for two elements in a single DOM, but they both require different events.

```
$("div.form-group").children("input,button").on("click blur",function(){
    console.log("GO!");
});
```

This was my original idea, but when I was testing it out it also executed when focusing in to the text field! I only want it to execute when clicking a button or exiting a text field. (Like below, which does not actually work.)

```
$("div.form-group").children("input,button").on("button.click input.blur",function(){
    console.log("GO!");
});
```

Any ideas, or do I need two separate statements?

Comment: Yup... You require two event listeners for that.

Comment: 2 DOMs x 2 events = 4 handlers. Unless you rewrite jQuery on function :D

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant two elements in a single DOM. Editing to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `e.target.nodeName` and `e.type` and run function accordingly. As you can see function runs only when you click button or remove focus on input.

```js
function go() {
  console.log("GO!");
}

$('input, button').on('click blur', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && e.type == 'blur') go();
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON' && e.type == 'click') go();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Btn</button>
<input type="text">
```